# 3D scatter plot, assign color to a point based on a field

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, plotly

I am trying to color each point on my scatterplot according to the continent it is on. I have my code below but I am unsure as to how I can reference the continent  field for each entry, and then assign it to the color field in trace1.

I tried something such as below but no luck.

EDIT:: This has been answered -> Also, how can I pull from the github?

Here is my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.11.1.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  </body>

<body>
  <svg id="visualisation" width="1355" height="333"></svg>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.11.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
    d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/4_ThreeNum.csv', function(err, rows){
function unpack(rows, key) {
    return rows.map(function(row)
    { return row[key]; });}


    const asia = [];
    const condition = unpack(rows, 'continent');
    const j = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < condition.length;i++ ){
      if(condition[i] === 'asia'){
        asia[j] = condition[i];
        j++;
      }
    }
    console.log(asia[0]);


  var trace1 = {
  x:unpack(rows, 'lifeExp'), y: unpack(rows, 'gdpPercap'), z: unpack(rows, 'pop'),
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
        size: 12,
        line: {
        color: 'rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.14)',
        width: 0.5},
        opacity: 0.8},
    type: 'scatter3d'
};


var data = [trace1];
var layout = {
  width: 1000,
  height: 1000,
    margin: {
    l: 0,
    r: 0,
    b: 100,
    t: 0
  },
  scene: {
      xaxis: { title: asia[1] },
      yaxis: { title: "Population" },
      zaxis: { title: "GDP per cap" },
    },
  };
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
});

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Henry No sorry, habit.

Comment: Does using `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/4_ThreeNum.csv` instead work?

Comment: Yes, thanks Henry, Should have caught that myself.